# Does anyone have any idea to track event of google analytics programatically?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone have any idea to track event of google analytics programatically in asp.net?
thanks advanced

Comment: Could you elaborate further what you want to do? Add custom events?

Comment: i want add event track when new user sign up in my asp.net website using google analytics

Comment: are you using WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Postback simply write a javascript that creates the custom event.

(this code snippet assumes that you've already initialized the google analytics script)

Aspx:

```
<script>
<asp:literal id="LoggedInGAEvent" runat="server"></asp:literal>
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    string GoogleAnalyticsString = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'User', '{0}', '{1}']);";
    if (UserSuccesfullyLoggedIn)
        LoggedInGAEvent.Text = String.Format(GoogleAnalyticsString, "successfulLogin", username);
    else
        LoggedInGAEvent.Text = String.Format(GoogleAnalyticsString, "loginfailedn", username);
}
```

Comment: There's this, and then [there's always the official way to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx). :)

Comment: That's right, but I prefer to have the full control of how, when and where my code appears.. maybe it's just me, but I feel a lot more comfortable doing such things by hand.

Comment: thanks ramsesorginal i will try it and will tell you the result